# Не задается значение default для ComboBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Есть ComboBox с двумя параметрами. Требуется чтобы в нем по default уже стояло одно из значений. Параметр SelectedIndex установлен, но ComboBox все равно загружается без default значения.

```
<ComboBox Name="StatusAssetClass"
          Background="White"
          Height="45"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Margin="16,10,16,10"
          SelectedIndex="0"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Status, Mode=OneWay}"
          Style="{StaticResource ValidatableComboBoxStyle}"
          SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedStatus, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBoxItem>Active</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Inactive</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите SelectedIndex, оставьте только SelectedItem

Comment: Убрал. Результат все равно как на картинке

Comment: А вы SelectedStatus в коде устанавливаете после запуска?

Comment: SelectedStatus это DependencyProperty, чтобы получить то что было выбрано "Active" или "Inactive"

Comment: Во-первых, не стоит одновременно добавлять Items (ComboBoxItem) и привязываться к ItemsSource. Удивительно, что вообще работает приложение. Во-вторых, не понятно к чему байндится ваша SelectedItem. На вашем месте, если вам нужен комбобокс с этими двумя пунктами, то я бы: 1) Убрал ItemsSource. 2) SelectedIndex оставил равным 0. 3) SelectedItem забайндил к свойству в одном направлении (Mode=OneWayToSource). А если вам нужно ещё и менять статус из кода, то убрал бы SelectedItem вообще и привязался бы только к SelectedIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <ComboBox
            Name="StatusAssetClass"
            Background="White"
            Height="45"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="16,10,16,10"
            SelectedIndex="0"
            Style="{StaticResource ValidatableComboBoxStyle}">
            <ComboBoxItem>Active</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Inactive</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Данные получаю с ComboBox таким способом:

```
StatusAssetClass.SelectionBoxItem.ToString()
```

Comment: Ну, то есть вы так и не разобрались с привязками к свойствам, а решили поработать привычно в стиле WinForms - мешанина кода в обработчиках событий, т.е. весь код в кодбихайнд.

Answer (score 3):

[image: пример работы]

Создадим такую ViewModel

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly IMainPage _mainPage;

    //ctor
    public MainPageViewModel(IMainPage mainPage)
    {
        _mainPage = mainPage ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mainPage));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Содержимое комбобокса
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> StatusList { get; set; } = new List<string> { "Active", "Inactive" };


    /// <summary>
    /// Индекс выбранного в комбобоксе
    /// </summary>
    private int _SelectedIndexStatus;
    public int SelectedIndexStatus
    {
        get { return _SelectedIndexStatus; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedIndexStatus = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedIndexStatus)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка ОК
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand ButtonOKCommand => new DelegateCommand(OnButtonOK);
    private void OnButtonOK()
    {
        _mainPage.ShowMessage($"Вы выбрали: {StatusList[SelectedIndexStatus]}");
    }
}
```

Такой кодбихайнд

```
public interface IMainPage
{
    void ShowMessage(string message);
}

/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, IMainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //привязка ViewModel
        var vm = new MainPageViewModel(this);
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }


    public async void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(message);
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

XAML такой

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="100,0,0,0"
              Grid.Row="1"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="152"
              ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Content="OK"
            Margin="100,0,0,0"
            Grid.Row="2"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Command="{Binding ButtonOKCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

Comment: мой ComboBox используется находиться на control, который находиться на View, что немного меняют логику.

Comment: @AlexcandraKhotko "...ComboBox используется находиться на control..." - это как? Я не понял.

Comment: мой ComboBox находиться на InfoTabControl, а этот самый InfoTabControl передается на другую view с помощью привязки         <c:InfoTabControl/>

Comment: @AlexcandraKhotko под тегами к вашему вопросу есть пункт меню `править`. Добавьте полную вашего XAML с `<c:InfoTabControl/>` и тогда можно будет посмотреть как решить вашу проблему.

Comment: Мой ответ решает мою проблему.